# Do github personal access tokens provide write access to all public repos?

Tags: github, electron-builder

I'm trying to understand github personal access tokens and using travis-ci and/or AppVeyor to build my project and put the build results on github in the releases

I'm using Electron-Builder.

[The instructions](https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish) say to [generate a personal access token on github](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and store it as an encrypted environment variable on the CI.

What I don't understand thought is it seems like that token is global. Instead of giving the CI permission to push things to a single repo I'm giving it permission to push things to all repos (I have over 200 at the moment).

Is that really the case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @einpoklum, the guidelines include "software tools commonly used by programmers;". I see your point but using a CI to build your software is just a remote tool, no? It seems to me this question is no different than asking about git or github and pretty important to know if you're giving some 3rd party a kind of write access to all your public repos.

Comment: The thing is, it seems to me the question is more about GitHub than about developing software (with or without GitHub).

Comment: @enipoklum, is that not true for pretty much all the questions on the right under "related"? Should I go vote to close all of those?

Comment: Almost all of these were written before webapps.stackexchange.com was available. There are lots of questions, even very highly-voted ones, which today would not be accepted on the site.

Comment: @einpoklum, I see your point. It seems like webapps is for end users running gmail, outlook, slack, twitter. Asking about deployment via github is clearly a developer question just as ask asking about the slack API or the twitter API where as asking how to post a photo on twitter or how to format a message on slack or format a cell in gsheets would belong on webapps. At least that's my understanding. This question seems related to software development which is off topic for webapps AFAICT